# Asynchronous Majordomo Pattern example using the CZMQ-4.1.0 new zsock API updated not working

Tags: c, multithreading, zeromq

After installing zmq and czmq with brew, I tried to compile and play the  [Asynchronous-Majordomo-Pattern](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Asynchronous-Majordomo-Pattern) but it did not work as it requires czmq v3. As far as I understood, I tried to update it to the v4, using **`zactor`** because

> **`zthread`** is deprecated in favor of **`zactor`** http://czmq.zeromq.org/czmq3-0:zthread

So right now the following code looks fine to me as updated async-majordomo pattern, but it does not work as expected, It does not create any thread when I run it via my terminal.

```
//  Round-trip demonstrator
//  While this example runs in a single process, that is just to make
//  it easier to start and stop the example. The client task signals to
//  main when it's ready.

#include "czmq.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

void dbg_write_in_file(char * txt, int nb_request) {
    FILE * pFile;
    pFile = fopen ("myfile.txt","a");

    if (pFile!=NULL)
    {
        fputs (txt, pFile);

        char str_nb_request[12];
        sprintf(str_nb_request, "%d", nb_request);
        fputs (str_nb_request, pFile);

        fputs ("\n", pFile);
        fclose (pFile);
    }
}

static void
client_task (zsock_t *pipe, void *args)
{
    zsock_t *client = zsock_new (ZMQ_DEALER);
    zsock_connect (client, "tcp://localhost:5555");
    printf ("Setting up test...\n");
    zclock_sleep (100);

    printf("child 1: parent: %i\n\n", getppid());
    printf("child 1: my pid: %i\n\n", getpid());

    int requests;
    int64_t start;

    printf ("Synchronous round-trip test...\n");
    start = zclock_time ();
    for (requests = 0; requests < 10000; requests++) {
        zstr_send (client, "hello");

        // stuck here /!\

        char *reply = zstr_recv (client);
        zstr_free (&reply);

        // check if it does something
        dbg_write_in_file("sync round-trip requests : ", requests);
        // end check
    }
    printf (" %d calls/second\n",
        (1000 * 10000) / (int) (zclock_time () - start));

    printf ("Asynchronous round-trip test...\n");
    start = zclock_time ();
    for (requests = 0; requests < 100000; requests++) {
        zstr_send (client, "hello");

        // check if it does something
        dbg_write_in_file("async round-trip send requests : ", requests);
        // end check
    }
    for (requests = 0; requests < 100000; requests++) {
        char *reply = zstr_recv (client);
        zstr_free (&reply);

        // check if it does something
        dbg_write_in_file("async round-trip rec requests : ", requests);
        // end check
    }
    printf (" %d calls/second\n",
        (1000 * 100000) / (int) (zclock_time () - start));

    zstr_send (pipe, "done");
}

//  Here is the worker task. All it does is receive a message, and
//  bounce it back the way it came:

static void
worker_task (zsock_t *pipe, void *args)
{
    printf("child 2: parent: %i\n\n", getppid());
    printf("child 2: my pid: %i\n\n", getpid());

    zsock_t *worker = zsock_new (ZMQ_DEALER);
    zsock_connect (worker, "tcp://localhost:5556");

    while (true) {
        zmsg_t *msg = zmsg_recv (worker);
        zmsg_send (&msg, worker);    
    }
    zsock_destroy (&worker);
}

//  Here is the broker task. It uses the zmq_proxy function to switch
//  messages between frontend and backend:

static void
broker_task (zsock_t *pipe, void *args)
{
    printf("child 3: parent: %i\n\n", getppid());
    printf("child 3: my pid: %i\n\n", getpid());

    //  Prepare our sockets
    zsock_t *frontend = zsock_new (ZMQ_DEALER);
    zsock_bind (frontend, "tcp://localhost:5555");
    zsock_t *backend = zsock_new (ZMQ_DEALER);
    zsock_bind (backend, "tcp://localhost:5556");
    zmq_proxy (frontend, backend, NULL);

    zsock_destroy (&frontend);
    zsock_destroy (&backend);
}

//  Finally, here's the main task, which starts the client, worker, and
//  broker, and then runs until the client signals it to stop:

int main (void)
{
    //  Create threads
    zactor_t *client = zactor_new (client_task, NULL);
    assert (client);    
    zactor_t *worker = zactor_new (worker_task, NULL);
    assert (worker);
    zactor_t *broker = zactor_new (broker_task, NULL);
    assert (broker);

    //  Wait for signal on client pipe
    char *signal = zstr_recv (client);
    zstr_free (&signal);

    zactor_destroy (&client);
    zactor_destroy (&worker);
    zactor_destroy (&broker);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run it, it looks like the program is stuck at the comment

> // stuck here /!\

Then when I kill it as it does not finish, or print anything at all, I need to press five time <kbd>**Ctrl+C**</kbd> ( ^C ). Only then, it looks more verbose on the console, like it was indeed running. 
=> Note that I delete all my `printf()` steps' outputs, as it was really messy to read.

When it runs, it does not write anything to the file, called by the *`dbg_write_in_file()`* function, only after sending five <kbd>**Ctrl+C**</kbd> ( ^C ).

Both client worker and broker task return the same `getppid` number ( my terminal ) and `getpid` as the program itself.

I use `gcc trippingv4.c -o trippingv4 -L/usr/local/lib -lzmq -lczmq` to compile.

When I try to kill it :

```
./trippingv4
Setting up test...
child 1: parent: 60967

child 1: my pid: 76853

Synchronous round-trip test...
^Cchild 2: parent: 60967

child 2: my pid: 76853

^Cchild 3: parent: 60967

child 3: my pid: 76853

^C^C^CE: 18-02-28 00:16:37 [76853]dangling 'PAIR' socket created at src/zsys.c:471
E: 18-02-28 00:16:37 [76853]dangling 'DEALER' socket created at trippingv4.c:29
E: 18-02-28 00:16:37 [76853]dangling 'PAIR' socket created at src/zsys.c:471
E: 18-02-28 00:16:37 [76853]dangling 'DEALER' socket created at trippingv4.c:89
```

**Update**

Thanks for the detailed answer @user3666197. In first part, the compiler does not compile the assert call so I just show the value instead and compare visually, they are the same.

```
int czmqMAJOR,
czmqMINOR,
czmqPATCH;

zsys_version ( &czmqMAJOR, &czmqMINOR, &czmqPATCH );
printf( "INF: detected CZMQ ( %d, %d, %d ) -version\n",
         czmqMAJOR,
         czmqMINOR,
         czmqPATCH
         );

printf( "INF: CZMQ_VERSION_MAJOR %d, CZMQ_VERSION_MINOR %d, CZMQ_VERSION_PATCH %d\n",
         CZMQ_VERSION_MAJOR,
         CZMQ_VERSION_MINOR,
         CZMQ_VERSION_PATCH
         );
```

Output :

```
INF: detected CZMQ ( 4, 1, 0 ) -version
INF: CZMQ_VERSION_MAJOR 4, CZMQ_VERSION_MINOR 1, CZMQ_VERSION_PATCH 0
```

The zsys_info call does compile but does not show anything on the terminal, even with a `fflush(stdout)` just in case so I just used `printf` :

```
INF: This system's Context() limit is 65535 ZeroMQ socketsINF: current state of the global Context()-instance has:
     ( 1 )-IO-threads ready
     ( 1 )-ZMQ_BLOCKY state
```

Then I changed the global context thread value with `zsys_set_io_threads(2)` and/or `zmq_ctx_set (aGlobalCONTEXT, ZMQ_BLOCKY, false);`, still blocked. It looks like zactor does not works with systems threads as zthread was... or does not gives a similar behavior. Given my experience in zeromq (also zero) probably I trying something that can't be achieved.

**Update solved but unproper**

My main error was to not have properly initiate zactor instance

> An actor function MUST call zsock_signal (pipe) when initialized and MUST listen to pipe and exit on $TERM command.

And to not have blocked the zactor's proxy execution before it called `zactor_destroy (&proxy);`

I let the final code below but you still need to exit at the end with <kbd>**Ctrl+C**</kbd> because I did not figure it out how to manage `$TERM` signal properly. Also, zactor still appears to not use system theads. It's probably design like this but I don't know how it's work behind the wood.

```
//  Round-trip demonstrator
//  While this example runs in a single process, that is just to make
//  it easier to start and stop the example. The client task signals to
//  main when it's ready.

#include <czmq.h>

static void
client_task (zsock_t *pipe, void *args)
{
    assert (streq ((char *) args, "Hello, Client"));
    zsock_signal (pipe, 0);

    zsock_t *client = zsock_new (ZMQ_DEALER);
    zsock_connect (client, "tcp://127.0.0.1:5555");

    printf ("Setting up test...\n");
    zclock_sleep (100);

    int requests;
    int64_t start;

    printf ("Synchronous round-trip test...\n");
    start = zclock_time ();
    for (requests = 0; requests < 10000; requests++) {
        zstr_send (client, "hello");

        zmsg_t *msgh = zmsg_recv (client);
        zmsg_destroy (&msgh);

    }
    printf (" %d calls/second\n",
        (1000 * 10000) / (int) (zclock_time () - start));

    printf ("Asynchronous round-trip test...\n");
    start = zclock_time ();
    for (requests = 0; requests < 100000; requests++) {
        zstr_send (client, "hello");
    }
    for (requests = 0; requests < 100000; requests++) {
        char *reply = zstr_recv (client);
        zstr_free (&reply);
    }
    printf (" %d calls/second\n",
        (1000 * 100000) / (int) (zclock_time () - start));

    zstr_send (pipe, "done");
    printf("send 'done' to pipe\n");
}

//  Here is the worker task. All it does is receive a message, and
//  bounce it back the way it came:

static void
worker_task (zsock_t *pipe, void *args)
{
    assert (streq ((char *) args, "Hello, Worker"));
    zsock_signal (pipe, 0);

    zsock_t *worker = zsock_new (ZMQ_DEALER);
    zsock_connect (worker, "tcp://127.0.0.1:5556");

    bool terminated = false;
    while (!terminated) {
        zmsg_t *msg = zmsg_recv (worker);
        zmsg_send (&msg, worker);
        // zstr_send (worker, "hello back"); // Give better perf I don't know why

    }
    zsock_destroy (&worker);
}

//  Here is the broker task. It uses the zmq_proxy function to switch
//  messages between frontend and backend:

static void
broker_task (zsock_t *pipe, void *args)
{
    assert (streq ((char *) args, "Hello, Task"));
    zsock_signal (pipe, 0);

    //  Prepare our proxy and its sockets
    zactor_t *proxy = zactor_new (zproxy, NULL);
    zstr_sendx (proxy, "FRONTEND", "DEALER", "tcp://127.0.0.1:5555", NULL);
    zsock_wait (proxy);
    zstr_sendx (proxy, "BACKEND", "DEALER", "tcp://127.0.0.1:5556", NULL);
    zsock_wait (proxy);

    bool terminated = false;
    while (!terminated) {
        zmsg_t *msg = zmsg_recv (pipe);
        if (!msg)
            break;              //  Interrupted
        char *command = zmsg_popstr (msg);

        if (streq (command, "$TERM")) {
            terminated = true;
            printf("broker received $TERM\n");
        }

        freen (command);
        zmsg_destroy (&msg);
    }

    zactor_destroy (&proxy);
}

//  Finally, here's the main task, which starts the client, worker, and
//  broker, and then runs until the client signals it to stop:

int main (void)
{

    //  Create threads
    zactor_t *client = zactor_new (client_task, "Hello, Client");
    assert (client);
    zactor_t *worker = zactor_new (worker_task, "Hello, Worker");
    assert (worker);
    zactor_t *broker = zactor_new (broker_task, "Hello, Task");
    assert (broker);

    char *signal = zstr_recv (client);
    printf("signal %s\n", signal);
    zstr_free (&signal);

    zactor_destroy (&client);
    printf("client done\n");
    zactor_destroy (&worker);
    printf("worker done\n");
    zactor_destroy (&broker);
    printf("broker done\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Let's diagnose the as-is state, going step by step:

```
int czmqMAJOR,
    czmqMINOR,
    czmqPATCH;

zsys_version ( &czmqMAJOR, &czmqMINOR, &czmqPATCH );
printf( "INF: detected CZMQ( %d, %d, %d )-version",
         czmqMAJOR,
         czmqMINOR,
         czmqPATCH
         );
assert ( czmqMAJOR == CZMQ_VERSION_MAJOR & "Major: does not match\n" );
assert ( czmqMINOR == CZMQ_VERSION_MINOR & "Minor: does not match\n" );
assert ( czmqPATCH == CZMQ_VERSION_PATCH & "Patch: does not match\n" );
```

if this matches your expectations, you may hope the DLL-versions are both matching and found in proper locations.

---

### Next:

may test the whole circus run in a non-blocking mode, to prove, there is no other blocker, but as briefly inspected, I have not found such option exposed in CZMQ-API, the native API allows one to flag a **`NOBLOCK`** option on `{ _send() | _recv() }-`operations, which prevents them from remaining blocked ( which may be the case for `DEALER` socket instance in cases on `_send()`-s, when there are not yet any counterparty with a POSACK-ed `.bind()/.connect()` state ).

Here I did not find some tools to do this as fast as expected in native API. Maybe you will have more luck on going through this.

---

### Test the presence of a global `Context()` instance, if it is ready:

add before a first socket instantiation, to be sure we are before any and all socket-generation and their respective `_bind()/_connect()` operation a following self-reporting row, using:

```
 zsys_info ( "INF: This system's Context() limit is %zu ZeroMQ sockets",
              zsys_socket_limit ()
              );
```

---

### One may also enforce the `Context()` instantiation manually:

so as to be sure the global Context() instance is up and running, before any higher abstracted instances ask if for implementing additional internalities ( sockets, counters, handlers, port-management, etc. )

```
//  Initialize CZMQ zsys layer; this happens automatically when you create
//  a socket or an actor; however this call lets you force initialization
//  earlier, so e.g. logging is properly set-up before you start working.
//  Not threadsafe, so call only from main thread. Safe to call multiple
//  times. Returns global CZMQ context.
CZMQ_EXPORT void *
    zsys_init (void);

//  Optionally shut down the CZMQ zsys layer; this normally happens automatically
//  when the process exits; however this call lets you force a shutdown
//  earlier, avoiding any potential problems with atexit() ordering, especially
//  with Windows dlls.
CZMQ_EXPORT void
    zsys_shutdown (void);
```

and possibly better tune IO-performance, using this right at the initialisation state:

```
//  Configure the number of I/O threads that ZeroMQ will use. A good
//  rule of thumb is one thread per gigabit of traffic in or out. The
//  default is 1, sufficient for most applications. If the environment
//  variable ZSYS_IO_THREADS is defined, that provides the default.
//  Note that this method is valid only before any socket is created.
CZMQ_EXPORT void
    zsys_set_io_threads (size_t io_threads);
```

This manual instantiation gives one an additional benefit, from having the instance-handle void pointer, so that one can inspect it's current state and shape by **`zmq_ctx_get()`** tools:

```
void *aGlobalCONTEXT = zsys_init();

printf( "INF: current state of the global Context()-instance has:\n" );
printf( "     ( %d )-IO-threads ready\n", zmq_ctx_get( aGlobalCONTEXT,
                                                       ZMQ_IO_THREADS
                                                       )
        );
printf( "     ( %d )-ZMQ_BLOCKY state\n", zmq_ctx_get( aGlobalCONTEXT,
                                                       ZMQ_BLOCKY
                                                       )
        ); // may generate -1 in case DLL is << 4.2+
...
```

---

---

### If unhappy with signal-handling, one may design and use another one:

```
//  Set interrupt handler; this saves the default handlers so that a
//  zsys_handler_reset () can restore them. If you call this multiple times
//  then the last handler will take affect. If handler_fn is NULL, disables
//  default SIGINT/SIGTERM handling in CZMQ.
CZMQ_EXPORT void
    zsys_handler_set (zsys_handler_fn *handler_fn);
```

where

```
//  Callback for interrupt signal handler
typedef void (zsys_handler_fn) (int signal_value);
```